# Angular material tab navigation loses active mark when route query parameters change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material navigation tab:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link
        [routerLink]="'firstRoute'"
        [queryParams]="{param1: value1, param2: value2}"
        routerLinkActive #rla1="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="rla1.isActive">
    Import
    </a>
    <a mat-tab-link
        [routerLink]="'secondRoute'"
        [queryParams]="{param1: value1, param2: value2}"
        routerLinkActive #rla2="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="rla2.isActive">
    Database
    </a>
</nav>
```

Everything works fine, until I change query parameters value:

```
changeQueryParams() {
    const params = {
      param1: 'newValue1',
      param2: 'newValue2'
    };
    this.router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: params });
}
```

Every time I call this method, current tab loses activation mark (blue border below text). What I missed here ?

Comment: remove relative To and check

Comment: removing 'relativeTo' from this.router.navigate does not help.

Comment: what is the value of value1 variable

Comment: try to print the value of  rla1.isActive and rla2_isActive and check

Comment: Variables has string value. For example: {param1: 'John', param2: '2018-11-12'} and when I change params to {param1: 'John', param2: '2018-11-15'}, activation loses.

Comment: How to print rla1.isActive and rla2_isActive ?

Comment: i think it is due to mis match of queryParams. you have static param1 value inside your method

Comment: What do you mean when you say "static param1" ? Both parameters are query parameters , and they are changeable.

Comment: But inside changequery method you are passing newvalue1 string

Comment: Maybe I don't understand it. What then I should send there if string value is not correct :) ?

Answer (score 0):

probably it is a bit late, but try adding queryParamsHandling="merge" to the mat-tab-link tag. It will also keep the parameters when you navigate between tabs.

```
<a mat-tab-link
    [routerLink]="'firstRoute'"
    [queryParams]="{param1: value1, param2: value2}"
    routerLinkActive #rla1="routerLinkActive"
    queryParamsHandling="merge"
    [active]="rla1.isActive">
Import
</a>
```

It works for me.